# details about moneybookrs merchant_fields?

Tags: payment-gateway

Any body know details about merchant_fields in moneybookers (SKRILL).
Suppose I send this 
merchant_fields = 'f1,f2,f3'

What it means .
Is it means I also have to send f1= something ?

and they will return me this f1 value.

and get that value through f1 = $_POST['f1']

Comment: Ah .... Well that makes it crystal clear! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When preparing the payment and sending the `merchant_fields` parameter, you are kind of white-listing the parameters. So if you send `merchant_fields` = "f1,f2,f3" you also have to send the parameters with their values (f1 = "abc", f2 = "def", f3 = "ghi").

Moneybookers/Skrill will POST these values (among others) to the URL specified with the `status_url` parameter. The documentation doesn't really make clear how the merchant fields are passed to the status_url, but I found out they're just passed as additional POST params with param names as previously defined (you can access them e.g. via PHP with `$field1 = $_POST['f1'];`.

Always check the MD5 signature to make sure the request is really from Moneybookers/Skrill!